# Aws amplify access management

Tags: aws-amplify

I have one root user for aws amplify account. I have created 4 apps. I wanted to give access to only 1 app to the users. How do I do that?

Trying to understand roles & users

Answer (score 0):

Usually AWS Amplify assigns the AdministratorAccess-Amplify Policy to your user.

If you look at your user permissions, it should like something like this for the resource:

```
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:cloudformation:*:*:stack/amplify-*"
        ]
```

The `*` at the end means all of them.

Create a new Policy by and change the stars to the ARN for the resource you want the users to have access to for each one.